# Is there something like SqlAlchemy's SqlSoup for Java?

Tags: java, sql, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm looking for a Java ORM that works from database reflection - I need to just point it at a DB, and start being able to walk through the entire set of tables, etc.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

There are reverse-engineering tools

- [NetBeans - ReverseEngineering](http://wiki.netbeans.org/ReverseEngineering)
- [JBoss - Chapter 6. Controlling reverse engineering](http://www.redhat.com/docs/en-US/JBoss_Developer_Studio/en/hibernatetools/html/reverseengineering.html),

but I am not aware of any `runtime` extensions that would do the job as nicely as `SqlSoup` does. It is not impossible in Java, but I have never seen it and would be happy to learn if there is one.